# How many sticks to make a grid of squares?

Tags: mathematics

We can arrange short sticks to make grid of squares, as in the 3 x 3 example of the figure below, which requires 24 sticks. How many sticks are required to make a 151 x 143 grid of squares?

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it appears to be a puzzle found elsewhere and also just a mathematical problem (rather than a mathematical puzzle)

Comment: "*of the figure below*" - which figure? I think you forgot to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Each "point" has 2 attached sticks. Except last (or first) row and last (or first) column which has one more.
So I think it would be

> 151 * 143 * 2 + 151 + 143 = 43480

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions

Answer (score 0):

> A (R x C) grid of squares made from sticks has (C+1) columns of sticks and (R+1) rows of sticks.

> Each row has C sticks. Each column has R sticks.

> Vertical sticks (columns) = (C+1)(R) = RC+R Horizontal sticks (rows) = (R+1)(C) = RC+C

> Total = 2RC + R + C

---

Math check:

> 1x1 = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4

> 1x2 = 4 + 1 + 2 = 7

> 3x3 = 18 + 3 + 3 = 24

> 151x143 = 2(151x143)+151+143 = 43480

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions